# Inner product space proof

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

How do we prove that ||v|| = ||w|| iff (v-w) $ \bot $ (v+w).

I proceeded by starting from $ \langle v-w,v+w \rangle $ =0 and reach at 
$\langle v,v\rangle + \langle v,w \rangle $$= \langle w,v \rangle + \langle w,w \rangle $ and am stuck. Could you help me figure this out?

Comment: $\langle v-w, v+w \rangle = \|v\|^2 - \|w\|^2$.

Comment: It is a *real* inner product, right?

Comment: @ njguliyev But how do we arrive at that bçoz I'm getting the relation shown in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the inner product is real the claim is true since

$$(v-w)\perp(v+w)\iff 0=\langle v-w,v+w\rangle=||v||^2-||w||^2\ldots\;etc.$$

But if the inner product is complex then

$$0=\langle v-w,v+w\rangle=||v||^2-||w||^2+\langle v,w\rangle-\langle w,v\rangle=$$

$$=||v||^2-||w||^2+\langle v,w\rangle-\overline{\langle v,w\rangle}=||v||^2-||w||^2+2\,\text{Im}(\langle v,w\rangle)$$

and the claim's false in general.

Comment: @ Don. Thanks a ton Don. The question did not mention if the field is real but I'll take that to be the case.